# Screwed list padding from Firefox or IE

Tags: css

im wondering about this and have no idea where it comes from:

- Firefox 11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyNth.jpg
- Internet Explorer 9: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpctE.jpg

I did set in the start of the file (its the only css file):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}
```

And this is the complete style of the #top-Div-Container:

```
#top {

}
#top a {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #ADD2F8;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#top a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#top ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#top li {
    float: left;
}
```

Help and Promotions are simple Links. Only Login, Request Password and Register are in a list-Tag but here is the HTML:

```
<div id="top">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="/prizeplay/help">Help</a>
    <a href="/prizeplay/promotions">Promotions</a>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a name="Login" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a style="font-weight: bold; color: #FFDE00;" href="/prizeplay/request">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/prizeplay/request">Request password</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I dont understand this padding issue. Why is that?

Comment: put the actual html code rendered and not php code. one cant guess what is actually outputed and it is not complicated to do a -> "view source" and paste what is written.

Comment: Is this page available online for live-testing?

Comment: I ran your CSS and HTML through http://jsfiddle.net/B83zz/ and it looks fine across all browsers. Your problem lies in code that you did not provide.